How to host a webpack-based project with Firebase Hosting while maintaining functionality?
I’m trying to host my social media-like web app on Firebase Hosting. My project uses Webpack for bundling and includes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript(firebase) files. However, I’m facing issues with maintaining the functionality of my app after deploying it to Firebase.
This is my project structure



I configured Firebase Hosting and copied my dist/ files into the public/ folder.


Result: The website loads, but functionality breaks because the bundled files are not connected to the src/ files.


I considered moving all my dist/ and src/ files into the public/ folder to maintain the directory structure.


Problem: It seems unconventional and messy, and I’m unsure if this approach works with Firebase Hosting.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that you are confusing the public directory of firebase with public directory in your source code.
You do not need to copy your dist directory to public directory. Instead, update Firebase hosting config to treat dist directory as root instead of public directory.
Secondly, dist files are sufficient in themselves. They do not require connecting back to your src directory. If that is the case, then you are doing something wrong during the build.
As per the image shared in comments, you are ignoring all files in firebase.json. remove */. Line.

I tried doing that and when I open it using live server it works perfectly (It displays the images and the function is correctly working because they are connected to the js files in the src folder). But when I test it using firebase serve , t doesn't work. It also seems like it isn't getting the images (it returns 404). Here is an img demoing this error error img

Remove line #6 */. From the ignore list.

I don't understand what that does.It didn't work. But I moved my images folder inside the dist for easy access and it is working as I wanted.
Thank you
